# Python - как можно сравнить даты?

Tags: python

Вопрос - на сервер приходит запрос только с датой, без времени, а в базе в столбце created_date хранится дата вместе с временем. Как можно сравнить даты так, чтобы узнать совпадают ли дни, месяц и год без времени?

Comment: Зависит от того, как приходит и как хранится, пожалуйста больше подробностей

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь преобразованием формата даты в соответствии с вашей СУБД. Например, в `postgresql` это могло бы выглядеть так:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE DATE(created_date) = you_date
```

В данном примере функция `DATE` преобразует тип в нужный вам.